# sqlalchemy get model attribute question

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

My filters come via get params like so: filterName = 'email', filterValue = 'john@' and I need to build my query based on them.

If I try to use `rows.filter( getattr( self.model, filterName ).like( filterValue + '%' ) )` I get an error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'like'`

Since both my model and filter params come through GET it's crucial I implement a fix for this. How would you suggest?

Comment: That looks like it should work as long as you didn't previously assign the attribute "email" to the model class (with a value of None). Is there some other place where that could have happened?

Comment: If I use `rows.filter( User.email.like( filterValue + '%' ) )` it works even if User.email has a value of None at that time but `rows.filter( getattr( self.model, filterName ).like( filterValue + '%' ) )` fails

Comment: what is the output of `type(self.model)` there?

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/uhSV9rrg

Comment: I see you DO have an actual attribute on the object named "email" with the value of None. See the value of `__dict__` in the link there. Somewhere else in your code you are adding that.

Comment: of course it has value None. It's sqlalchemy model/database column. If you call it without a query it will return None. Check my second comment on this: If I use `rows.filter( User.email.like( filterValue + '%' ) )` it works even if User.email has a value of None at that time but `rows.filter( getattr( self.model, filterName ).like( filterValue + '%' ) )` fails

Comment: Well, I can tell you that I also do this kind of thing (use getattr on models to get columns for a generic web interface) and it works for me. But it's hard to debug without seeing more of your code and interacting with a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show what self/self.model is in there. Normally it'd be a class name.

So if you have a model User

```
field = 'id'
field_val = 3
qry = Session.query(User).filter(getattr(User, field) == field_val)
```

should work out fine.

You're not using getattr from an instance (self), but from the class itself.

Comment: that works. what about the like() method which shouldbe attached to `getattr(User, field).like()`. then you will get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'like'`